# Return a string when no record found in SELECT query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a select query in Access VBA. This query is a record source for a report. This report is a Sub Report of a Sub Report. I need the query to produce a string when there is no record exist for any particular search. Therefore, this subreport could be shown in the main report

Query Name: Qry_To_Be_Imoroved.

```
SELECT To_Be_Improved.To_Be_Improved, To_Be_Improved.Record_ID, To_Be_Improved.ID
FROM To_Be_Improved
WHERE (((To_Be_Improved.Record_ID)=[Reports]![Incident_Report_Updated]![Record_ID]));
```

How can I amend this to add a string to "To_Be_Improved" column when there is no record for a query.

Comment: Have you seen the `Report_NoData()` event of the report if it's of any use? You can print text on the report or even change the recordset if that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to make the query give a result for no records you could have some VBA test for results:

```
Set myRecordset = db.OpenRecordset(mySQLquery)

 If myRecordset.RecordCount = 0 Then
     MsgBox "No records for this selection"
End If
```

Without knowing the particulars of your database it may also be possible to have a summary query that counts the number of records for each instance, then make another query based on that query with a SWITCH to give a text output:

```
Switch(numRecords=0,"To Be Improved",numRecords>0,"We good") AS To_Be_Improved
```

Comment: I have already incorporated a solution like that. When there is no record, the sub report will generate a line indicating "No Records Found", which ultimately shows the subreport. But I am thinking for another possibility to show the subreport even without any records in it.

Comment: You could have the subreport based on a results table. If there are no records found in your query you could put a "No result" entry in the table.